# Is there a way to export to a variable common command line operations?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

If I have an operation such as

```
ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command
```

is there a way I can assign this to a variable so that I do not have to type it out every time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to save the command and replay it often, you can make an alias:

```
alias myps='ps -u $USER -o pid,rss,command'
```

Now, you can re-run the command by typing:

```
$ myps
```

You can also store this in your `.bashrc` file or `.bash_profile`.

On the other hand, if you have GNU readline available, you might get by with something like this: <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd></kbd> `ps -u`

<kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd></kbd> does a history lookup; all you have to do is type a unique portion of a command, and then press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to execute it; or press <kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd></kbd> to abort.

Comment: Functions are preferred to aliases: `myps () { ps -u "$USER" -o pid,rss,command; }`

Comment: @chepner Really? Why so?

Comment: Several reasons: the quoting is easier (since the body is not evaluated until the function is called), functions can handle arguments (which aliases cannot), and the `bash` man page itself says "[f]or almost every purpose, aliases are superseded by shell functions."